# Automatically extract and rename extracted file according to archive's name

Tags: windows-7, command-line, 7-zip

I have a bunch of zip files in a folder. Each zip file has a file in it named `exp_1.txt`. I would like to unzip each zip file and rename the extracted file from each zip file to what the zip file was named.

The zip files names don't follow any pattern or date structure, but are all different. I have figured out how to get the `exp_1.txt` file extracted into the same directory as the zip file, but can't figure out the renaming of `exp_1.txt` to match what the zip file it was extracted from is named.

Once again in fewer words: from `TuesdayReport.zip` I want to extract the only file `exp_1.txt` and rename it to `TuesdayReport.txt` in the same directory as `TuesdayReport.zip`.

Currently I'm using `7z x` to extract the file to the same directory the zip file is located in. I would prefer to be able to run this from a batch file.

Comment: On which operating system?

Comment: Windows 7 64 bit sorry for leaving that out originally.

Comment: I can get it to name a folder the same name and put the file in that folder, but this really doesn't help me as the file is still named exp_1.txt and it just created a directory for it, any other options?

Answer (score 1):

why not using 7zip command line edition, that you can download from [here](http://downloads.sourceforge.net/sevenzip/7za920.zip)?

inside this zip file you can find a help file in CHm format that has all switches and commands that can help you during your batch process.

Comment: I can get it to name a folder the same name and put the file in that folder, but this really doesn't help me as the file is still named exp_1.txt and it just created a directory for it, any other options?

Answer (score 1):

```
forfiles /M *.zip /C "cmd /c C:\PROGRA~1\7-Zip\7z.exe e @file & ren exp_1.txt @fname.txt"
```

Comment: Welcome to the Super User!  While this may answer the question, it would be a better answer if you could explain *why* it does so.  We’re looking for comprehensive, high-quality answers that provide some explanation and context.  Don’t just give a one-line answer; explain why your answer is right, ideally with citations.  Answers that don’t include explanations may be removed.

Comment: Can you explain what this code does? As it stands, this isn't very useful and may be deleted.

Answer (score 1):

This will extract the file named `exp_1.txt` from every zip file in the current directory with the name same as zip file but with `txt` instead of `zip` extension:

`for %a in (*.zip) do @(7z l "%~a" -ir!exp_1.txt |findstr exp_1.txt) && 7z e "%~a" -ir!exp_1.txt -so >"%~na.txt"`

This is to be run directly from command line, if you want to run it from batch you'd need to double `%`

What it does:

- `for` loop enumerates every zip file
- first `7z` invocation together with `findstr` makes sure extract is run/a file is only produced if the archive contains particular file
- second `7z` invocation actually extracts the file into the standard output (`-so` switch) and redirects stdout to file named the same as archive (minus extension). The `%~n` modifier instructs cmd to take only base name (without extension)

Please note that if there are more than one file in the archive with the same name (in different directories) then it may produce unexpected results.

If you put it in batch then I would also suggest to set filename as variable (**before the loop**) to avoid repetition related errors (you need to enter it 3 times in the command above).